# Eject ipod from Rpi without disconnecting

Tags: power, peripherals

This is not a question on how to umount a drive.

I have a 2nd gen ipod nano (old) that works great but has 0 battery life.

I figure if I plug it into the raspberry, it can power it and it does. However, the ipod comes up with the Do not disconnect icon as if it is mounted. lsblk indicates it is connected at /dev/sda and df indicates that it is not mounted. In gui, by unmounting the drive this message goes away while still charging it.

I can only access the rpi by cli (ssh) and I am using raspbian.

Update:
Testing it in Linux Mint 17.1, I inserted it, and then removed it with the gui. Interestingly, after doing so it **isn't detected in lsusb** when initially plugging it in, it **is**.
That makes me wonder - can I do that manually in cli?

Comment: If it's not mounted then how do you dismount it in the GUI?  Which GUI?

Comment: Other guis in other distro's such as Linux Mint. Generally, the gui will automount the drive, something I should of mentioned. However, rasbian doesn't (cli only) and yet it seems to perceive it as connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the ipod comes up with the Do not disconnect icon as if it is mounted

Sounds like the problem [described here](http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/ejecting-ipod-under-linux).   Going by that, you first have to mount a partition.  However, I think that person may be slightly confused, since s/he's using a mount point with the `eject` command, and this is why it *seems* that it must be mounted first (also, `man eject` says explicitly that "if the device or a device partition is currently mounted, it is unmounted before ejecting").

So on the pi, I would first try just `sudo eject /dev/sda` and see if that works.

If it doesn't, then try mounting a partition.  To check what's available on `/dev/sda`:

```
ls /dev | grep sda
```

You can try those in succession until one works, e.g.:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Now try `sudo eject /dev/sda`.  This should also `umount` the partition(s).

Comment: I did this, it turns out the ipod has 2, sda1 and sda2. I couldn't mount sda1 (probably cause it's the software for the ipod in some proprietary format but the second was mountable (never checked the fs format) I mounted /dev/sda2 and then umounted it... No luck. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: I might have found something for you; I've edited that from the beginning to include `eject`, which signals the device in a way plain `umount` doesn't.

Comment: brilliant! Until this moment, eject had no other relevance to me other than ejecting a cd. As a note, it required root (sudo) access to complete -> eject: unable to open `/dev/sda' <- and required installation of eject (apt-get)